# Ethernet disconnected after sleep

Tags: ethernet

When I come back to my Mac after it was sleeping sometimes the Ethernet connection is not working. I have to unplug and plug it again.

I am using macOS Sierra
Version 10.12.6

Any ideas?

Comment: Similar questions: [On resume from sleep, DHCP or ARP on the ethernet is not working](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/65990/37797) and [Ethernet cable connected iMac fails to connect to Internet after sleep mode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/62617/37797) then a couple suffering from the issue due to using a USB adapter for Ethernet [Ethernet network connection lost after locking or after Screen Saver activation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/268072/37797) and [Third party USB Ethernet adapter won't wake up](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/213308/37797), are you using an adapter?

Comment: @grgarside Thanks but there is no real solutions

Comment: Mac model?  Do you have to unplug it or can you just renew the address? (In Network settings -> Advanced)

Comment: This issue is still not fixed by apple in 10.13.1, on a brand new macbook pro.  googling, there is still no solution.